# UILabel min font size shadow issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uilabel, font-size

I have an issue when setting minimum font size on my `UILabels`. As you can see the shadow isn't following along with the font size. It's supposed to be just 1 px heigh.

**My label:**

[image: UILabel settings simulator]

**My settings:**

[image: UITableViewCell IB]

Comment: once check in .m file  somewhere else you kept the shadow offset value?

Comment: The only place I set the shadow offset is in interface builder

Comment: once set offset by programatically?

Comment: Yeah, with the following code: `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;
        label.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor];
        label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: And I get the same behavior

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn off "Tighten Letter Spacing".

There seems to be a bug with shadows, auto shrinking, and auto tightening.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. You might also consider filing a bug report so this will hopefully get fixed with iOS 7.

Comment: Thx, this saved my day. I new it must be some kind of iOS7 bug. I am working with xCode4 and get it on the iOS7 device with an adHoc installation. That's not the best debugging scenario ... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Set the `shadow.offset` programmatically based on font size.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the Value 12 Below the Minimum Font Size you can't set this value its Too large pass it like 0.5 or 0.8 something Like that.

Secondly your Vertical Shadow Offset is 1 so there is no chance to take that much of shadow It may be possible that you have passed shadow through Code please check it first.

When you check it in xib File while changing at that time if its not change that just reopen the Window than It'll Work.

Hope this will Help.

Comment: What do you mean with 12 is to large? Is it supposed to be in a scale 0.1 to 1? I have checked the code for places where I set the shadow offset but there is none.

Comment: @DanielTovesson yeah it shuold be between 0 to 1. Also when you change it through XIB you'll able to see the changes at a time there in the XIB so i want to know you are getting right there ?

Comment: Ok, thought that scale was for the other option: "Minimum Font Scale". Anyway, I tried to set it to 0,9 and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: @DanielTovesson its for not our solution just it was wrong thats why i said, Ok i want to know that when you are changing it from settings you can see the same thing in the xib ?

Comment: Yes, interface builder shows the same thing if I change the text there.

Comment: That Should not been occur than now do 1 thing Take new Label Give it try to Give shadow effect in it remove the Previous Label.