# UILabel with Shadow changes Shadow Offset when Autoshrinking

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel with a white shadow offset at 1 vertical pixel and it looks fine at its normal size: http://cl.ly/PBtC

But if the text inside the label gets large enough for Autoshrink to scale it down the shadow offset grows much more than a pixel. See here: http://cl.ly/PC4M

And the offset amount seems to change based on how much the UILabel is Autoshrunk: http://cl.ly/PBtn

Has anyone seen this? There is nothing funny about my UILabel and it is very repeatable. Here are my IB settings: http://cl.ly/PCIx

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue (supposedly an IB bug). As of now (Xcode 4.6.2), it seems that one can have **either `Minimum Font Scale` or `Tighten Letter Spacing` enabled**. <s>`Minimum Font Size` seems to work fine with `Tighten Letter Spacing`.</s>

Also take a look at [UILabel min font size shadow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164466/uilabel-min-font-size-shadow-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my best guess is that UILabel is not handling the autoresize properly with respect to the shadow. 
I would recommend creating a UILabel subclass, and handling the shadow manually by overriding `layoutSubviews`. If you can confirm that it is a UIKit bug, file a report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same exact result using your IB settings.

For a fix, change the text type to attributed text and everything works fine as is.

Comment: When I change the UILabel to be attributed text instead of plain I lose my size and alignment settings from Interface Builder. I am setting the text with: [_stringLabel setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:value]];

It doesn't seem to respect my interface builder settings.

Comment: It's not respecting your IB values because you are re-initializing the NSAttributedString.  Set the outlet and assign the text through that, I don't think there is a reason to re-initialize the string.  If there is, then manually set your alignment and size in code directly after you alloc init it.  Hopefully this fixes your problem, please let me know.

Comment: The same thing happens when I just use [_stringLabel setText:value]. Not sure why it won't just use IB values.

Comment: Its a pain and I shouldn't have to. Why have IB settings if they don't work? Can you think of any other reasons why this is failing?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're still reinitializing somewhere.  IB is still pretty buggy from what I've seen, hardly a finished product.  I'll try and recreate what's happening to you with assigning text in a bit and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot.